# Character only being counted as invalid

Tags: c, character

The program was crashing, but not that is fixed. Currently every character entered is coming back invalid in the while loop.

```
char get_yes_or_no_character(void)
/*
  This is to purely get the Y or N for options
*/
{
  char choice = '\0';
  choice = printf("Would you like to use this roll for a game combination? Press Y for yes or N for no!\n");
  scanf(" %c", &choice);
  return choice;
}

char choice_input_validation(char choice)
/*
  This makes sure that input validation for the character is correct
*/
{
  while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
  {
    printf("Invalid option, try again\n");
    choice = printf("Would you like to use this roll for a game combination? Press Y for yes or N for no!\n");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
  }
  return choice;
}
```

This is a snippet of it the code

```
if (roll < 3)
{
  choice = get_yes_or_no_character();
  choice = choice_input_validation(choice);
}
if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
{
  break;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c", choice);` ---> `scanf(" %c", &choice);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: gosh it was that easy... I hate when I can't catch stupid mistakes like that!

Comment: @LPs quick question, I fixed the &choice, but now every inputted character is coming back invalid, do you see a reason for this?

Comment: change all the `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line :

```
scanf(" %c", choice);
```

to :

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

`scanf` requires to take a pointer as argument.

---

Also change your `while` condition from :

```
while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
```

to :

```
while ( (choice != 'y') && (choice != 'Y') && (choice != 'n') && (choice != 'N') )
```

as you want to consider `choice` invalid if it **does not** have ***any*** of the previous values.

Comment: @sarahcampolt You are welcome, glad I helped :) If your problem is solved, you could accept one answer so that your question appears as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code

```
while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
    {
        printf("Invalid option, try again\n");
        choice = printf("Would you like to use this roll for a game combination? Press Y for yes or N for no!\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
    }
    return choice;
```

But when anyone enter the choice Y then the condition of while is always true because it is not equal to 'y'. That's why it goes into the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Also the line

```
while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
```

probably doesn't do what you're thinking it does because choice is always not one of those four characters - so it always evaluates to true.

```
while (!( choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y' || choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'))
```

Probably does the job (I haven't compiled it myself).